# Trying to get location of UI Automation element within window

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm trying to get the location of a hyperlink within a browser window with `UI Automation`.

I can use `elementLink.Current.BoundingRectangle` to get the "coordinates of the enclosing rectangle" according to MSDN. I believe however that these coordinates are related to the whole desktop and as I have 3 screens so I can't use them to click the hyper link. I know the location of the hyperlink in the window is 150 X 605 Y.

`BoundingRectangle.Location` on the element returns me -1144 X and 745 Y.

Can anyone tell me how to get the 150 X 605 Y coordinate of the link relative to its browser window?

Comment: If you've already got an appropriate element, and you want to click on it, why are you suddenly jumping out of "UI Automation" world and trying to find its screen location, rather than just using it's InvokePattern?

Comment: I believe UI automation needs focus on the window? I don't really want this to happen. I want it to be a process that runs in the background. I'm using PostMessage at the moment and it seems to work fine for sending keys, just need to get the mouse part of it working now which is what this question is for :-)